# Google oAuth API: How to show google login layer for unauthenticated users?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

On medium.com I have seen the this (layer on the bottom)

[image]

I assume this is displayed by google as medium does not have my info.
Is there any material available on this api? Is it something official?

Comment: see https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

Comment: @pinoyyid it seems that the whole layer comes from google (including personal information). nothing like that is mentioned in the doc? or do I get it wrong?